# Discord.js v12 send the error message from dm

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to sending the error message from dm to users. But I'm getting `ReferenceError: error is not defined` error. How can I fix this?

```
if (error) {
   client.users.cache.get(message.author.id).send(error)
}
```

Here is my index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`\x1b[33m${client.user.tag} \x1b[0mgiriş yaptı!`);
  client.user.setActivity(`Online on ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`, {type: 'WATCHING'})
});

client.on('message', message => {
  const { channel } = message

  if (channel.type === 'news') {
    message.crosspost().catch(console.error)
    console.log(`\x1b[31m${message.guild.name}\x1b[0m sunucusunda duyuru yapıldı! \x1b[33m(ID: ${message.guild.id})`)
  }

  if (error) {
    client.users.cache.get(message.author.id).send(error)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`\x1b[33m${client.user.tag} \x1b[0mgiriş yaptı!`);
  client.user.setActivity(`Online on ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers`, {type: 'WATCHING'})
});

client.on('message', message => {
  const { channel } = message

  if (channel.type === 'news') {
    message.crosspost().catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
      message.author.send(error.message)
    })
    console.log(`\x1b[31m${message.guild.name}\x1b[0m sunucusunda duyuru yapıldı! \x1b[33m(ID: ${message.guild.id})`)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to recognize 'error'. I don't know what your whole code is, but I prefer to use a catch instead.

```
.catch(error => {
     return <user>.send(error);
})
```

Comment: I tried but didn't work. I made send a message from dm but I want to send a private message to the error on the console.